# how to update AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, updates, abstracttablemodel

I made ​​reference to a number of methods.
That the effective way for fireTableCellUpdated.
But in fact I still do not apply.

How to make the table content update in the after DETA value update.

The method I call GJJ method implementation.
Although updated but the emergence of many new window.
This is not my needs.

Tell me how to add a button in the new window and listening button to perform the update behavior
friend told me how to do it.

```
         class MyTable extends AbstractTableModel {

    Object p[][]={  
                {DETA_1_1,DETA_1_2, DETA_1_3, DETA_1_4, DETA_1_5},
                {DETA_2_1,DETA_2_2, DETA_2_3, DETA_2_4, DETA_2_5},
                {DETA_3_1,DETA_3_2, DETA_3_3, DETA_3_4, DETA_3_5},
                {DETA_4_1,DETA_4_2, DETA_4_3, DETA_4_4, DETA_4_5},
                {DETA_5_1,DETA_5_2, DETA_5_3, DETA_5_4, DETA_5_5},
                {DETA_6_1,DETA_6_2, DETA_6_3, DETA_6_4, DETA_6_5},
                {DETA_7_1,DETA_7_2, DETA_7_3, DETA_7_4, DETA_7_5},
                {DETA_8_1,DETA_8_2, DETA_8_3, DETA_8_4, DETA_8_5},  
                {DETA_9_1,DETA_9_2,DETA_9_3,DETA_9_4,DETA_9_5},  
                {DETA_10_1,DETA_10_2,DETA_10_3,DETA_10_4,DETA_10_5},  
                {DETA_11_1,DETA_11_2,DETA_11_3,DETA_11_4,DETA_11_5},  
                {DETA_12_1,DETA_12_2,DETA_12_3,DETA_12_4,DETA_12_5},  
                {DETA_1_3_1,DETA_1_3_2,DETA_1_3_3,DETA_1_3_4,DETA_1_3_5},  
                {DETA_1_4_1,DETA_1_4_2, DETA_1_4_3, DETA_1_4_4, DETA_1_4_5},  
                {DETA_15_1,DETA_15_2,DETA_15_3,DETA_15_4,DETA_15_5},  
                {DETA_16_1,DETA_16_2,DETA_16_3,DETA_16_4,DETA_16_5},  
                {DETA_17_1,DETA_17_2,DETA_17_3,DETA_17_4,DETA_17_5},  
                {DETA_1_8_1,DETA_1_8_2,DETA_1_8_3,DETA_1_8_4,DETA_1_8_5},  
                {DETA_19_1,DETA_19_2,DETA_19_3,DETA_19_4,DETA_19_5}  
            };  
    String[] n = { "NO","CARD","NAME","NAME2","time" };

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return n.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return p.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return n[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return p[row][col];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

}

   private void GJJ() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    MyTable mt = new MyTable();
    JTable t = new JTable(mt);

    t.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(550, 30));
    JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(t);
    f.getContentPane().add(s, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setTitle("coolman");
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're question is a little vague.  "Updating" a table model could be updating existing model (ie editing the data) and/or adding new rows.

I've done a quick example of both.

When editing a row, the model will and table will update them selves, so you needn't do anything, however, if you add or remove rows, you will become responsible for firing the update events yourself.

```
public class TestTableModel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTableModel();
    }

    public TestTableModel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel();
                final JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

                JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
                addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        tableModel.add();
                    }
                });
                JButton updateButton = new JButton("Update");
                updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                        if (row > -1) {
                            table.setValueAt("Banana", row, 0);
                        }
                    }
                });

                JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
                buttonPane.add(addButton);
                buttonPane.add(updateButton);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Person {

        private String name;
        private int age;

        public Person() {
        }

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

    }

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Person> lstPeople;

        public MyTableModel() {
            lstPeople = new ArrayList<Person>(25);
            lstPeople.add(new Person("Darryl Garton", randomAge()));
            lstPeople.add(new Person("Neil Willison", randomAge()));
            lstPeople.add(new Person("Darryl Hege", randomAge()));
            lstPeople.add(new Person("Karina Jerry", randomAge()));
            lstPeople.add(new Person("Erik Leddy", randomAge()));
            lstPeople.add(new Person("Chandra Kehrer", randomAge()));
            lstPeople.add(new Person("Katy Sapien", randomAge()));
            lstPeople.add(new Person("Lonnie Blakes", randomAge()));
            lstPeople.add(new Person("Kelly Ruocco", randomAge()));
            lstPeople.add(new Person("Fernando Mckinnie", randomAge()));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        protected int randomAge() {

            return (int)Math.round(Math.random() * 99) + 1;

        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return lstPeople.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            String name = null;
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    name = "Name";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    name = "Age";
                    break;
            }
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            Class clazz = String.class;
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 1:
                    clazz = Integer.class;
                    break;
            }
            return clazz;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Object value = null;
            Person person = lstPeople.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    value = person.getName();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = person.getAge();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Person person = lstPeople.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    if (aValue instanceof String) {
                        person.setName(aValue.toString());
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (aValue instanceof Integer) {
                        person.setAge((Integer)aValue);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }

        public void add() {

            lstPeople.add(new Person());
            fireTableRowsInserted(lstPeople.size() - 1, lstPeople.size() - 1);

        }

    }

}
```

You might like to have a read through [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information

Comment: I mean I have a value.
Press the button, the value will be updated and the table will be updated too.

Comment: So, you could call [`Table#setValueAt(Object, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) directly, which will update the model (assuming you've overridden `setValueAt` in the model) and update the view

Comment: How can a simple demonstration to me to see?
Create a new class HG ();

class HG extends AbstractTableModel {
 Object getValueAt (int row, int col) {
return p [row] [col];
}
}

Fail.

Comment: I've updated the example to include an "update" button.  Select a row, click update, voila...